# Get value to max date

Tags: database, qlikview

I have a problem on on Qlikview.
I would like to get the associated value of the max date when I select and `ID`.
For example, if I have the following data:

```
id value date
1    2    1
1    4    2
1    6    3
1    5    4
```

When I select `ID=1` I would like to get the associated value of the max date (4), which is 5
Thank you!

Comment: and what database?  does it support analytical functions which would make this easy?

Comment: ops sorry, i use Clikview.

Comment: Can't find anything on that database.   maybe stefan has you covered with set analysis in Qlik

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set analysis` to achieve this:

`= Sum( {< date = {"$(=Max(date))"} >} value )`

You can read more about `set analysis` on [Qlik Help website](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm)